# Text area with autosuggest and removal functionality

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a simple messaging system. For composing the message, I provide a text area. This text area should have an autosuggest functionality and also something like a "remove" button.

Can you tell me how to implement this sort of functionality? I think there is a jQuery plugin to accomplish something like this, but I can't recall the name.

Here is a mockup of what I'm expecting:

[markup http://img138.yfrog.com/img138/6428/autosuggesttextarea.jpg](http://img138.yfrog.com/img138/6428/autosuggesttextarea.jpg)

Comment: Whereever the suggestions come from, text files or mysql database, you would need an ajax request to get the suggestion based on sofar entered text. What function is supposed to be connected with 'remove' button?

Comment: in some site , i find this sort of thins, likve textare with autosuggest, if entered name not intreset to process means we can remvoe from the list..using remove icon on the name label top corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like facebook autocomplete.

Try this: [Jquery](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) or [Prototype](http://www.interiders.com/2008/02/11/prototextboxlist-meets-autocompletion/)

Comment: exactyl this manner am looking ..is there any thing other links plz refer

Comment: Just try to google it. (keywords: javascript jquery prototype facebook autocomplete)